# Pegando dados jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um upload de imagens, onde é possível subir várias imagens. Quando a pessoas escolhe suas imagens, juntamente com Preview em `jQuery`, eu mostro 2 campos, um do link e outro da legenda da imagem. Porém, quando a pessoa clica em salvar, não consigo pegar estes dois campos, o restante vai perfeitamente. O que pode ser?

O código da pagina principal:

```
        <div class="span6 upl">
            <div id="tamb">Tamanho esperado: 586px x 184px</div>
           <input id="files" name="files[]" type="file" multiple />
            <output id="result" />

        </div>
```

O código js:

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){

    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");

            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];

                //Only pics
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                  continue;

                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                    var picFile = event.target;

                    var div = document.createElement("div");

                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/> <a href='#' class='remove_pict del'><i class=\"icon-remove\"></i></a> <div class=\"control-group\">                         <label class=\"control-label\" for=\"MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM\">Legenda</label>                          <div class=\"controls\"><input id=\"MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM\" name=\"MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM\" type=\"text\" class=\"input-xlarge\">     </div>                </div>         <div class=\"control-group pull-right linkImg\"><label class=\"control-label\" for=\"TXT_LINKX_URLXX\">Link</label><div class=\"controls\"><input id=\"TXT_LINKX_URLXX\" name=\"TXT_LINKX_URLXX\" type=\"text\" class=\"input-xlarge\">        </div>            </div>";

                    output.insertBefore(div,null);   
                    div.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                       div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                    });         

                });

                 //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }                               

        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
</script>
```

E, por último, o código PHP:

```
<?php
    // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");
    include ("../includes/suc_validacao.php");
    include ("../includes/suc.php");

    $cdClie = $_POST['COD_IDENT_CLIEN'];
    $titulo = $_POST['TXT_TITUL_PUBLI'];
    $status = $_POST['FLG_STATU_PUBLI'];
    $resumo = $_POST['TXT_RESMO_PUBLI'];
    $msg = $_POST['TXT_DETLH_PUBLI'];
    $link = $_POST['TXT_LINKX_URLXX'];
    $usurLoga = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];

            //INFO IMAGEM
            $file       = $_FILES['files'];
            $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));


    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_PUBLICACOES (COD_IDENT_CLIEN, TXT_TITUL_PUBLI, FLG_STATU_PUBLI, FLG_TIPOX_PAGIN, TXT_RESMO_PUBLI, TXT_DETLH_PUBLI, TXT_LINKX_URLXX,  COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL) VALUES";
    $query .=  "('$cdClie','$titulo','$status','012','$resumo','$msg','$link','$usurLoga', now())";

    $inserir = mysql_query($query)
    or die(error());

    $COD_IDENT_ULTIM_PUBLI = mysql_insert_id();

    $response = array("success" => true);

    // Recebeu a imagem
    if($numFile != NULL):

            //PASTA
            $folder     = '../uploads';

            //REQUISITOS
            $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg');
            $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

            //MENSAGENS
            $msg        = array();
            $errorMsg   = array(
                1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
                2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
                3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
                4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
            );

            if($numFile <= 0)
                echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
            else{
                for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
                    $name   = $file['name'][$i];
                    $type   = $file['type'][$i];
                    $size   = $file['size'][$i];
                    $error  = $file['error'][$i];
                    $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $legend = $file['MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM'][$i];
                    $link   = $file['TXT_LINKX_URLXX'][$i];

                    $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
                    $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

                    if($error != 0)
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
                    else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
                    else if($size > $maxSize)
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
                    else{

                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)){

                            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_IMAGENS (TXT_FILEN_IMAGN, MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM, TXT_LINKX_URLXX, FLG_TIPOX_IMAGEM, COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL) VALUES ('".$novoNome."', '".$legend."', '".$link."', 'I', '".$usurLoga."', now())");
                    $COD_IDENT_ULTIM_IMAGE = mysql_insert_id();
                    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS ( COD_IDENT_PUBLI, COD_SEQUN_IMAGM) VALUES ('".$COD_IDENT_ULTIM_PUBLI."', '".$COD_IDENT_ULTIM_IMAGE."')");


                        }else
                            $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";

                    }

                    foreach($msg as $pop)
                        echo $pop.'<br>';
                }
            }
    endif;

        mysql_close($conn);
        header("Location: publicacaoPF.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=$cdClie"); exit;

?>
```

Comment: Onde está o HTML para gravar e que código essa função corre?

Comment: Não existe código HTML sim o PHP, e este ja está la. e qual é o código para percorrer a função ? não sei qual é ?

Comment: Tens na pergunta "Porém, quando a pessoa clica em salvar,"... onde está esse código?

Comment: Não apresentei nele pois, é apenas redirecionar para pagina PHP citada, não existe mais nenhuma informação importante em outra pagina referente ao que eu quero, portanto, se não está escrito no código acima não desenvolvi, pois não estou entendendo, pois preciso da ajuda para finalizar.